# Record the desktop using Electron

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I am building an electron in which I need the `desktopCapturer` api, but I don't fully understand how to use it.

From the api official page (and this example app: https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/desktop-capture) I see that the `desktopCapturer` only gives me the id's of the sources, not the video streams themselves. For that, I should use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`.  But the constraints object no longer has the `mandatory` property and because I am using typescript I am getting an error if I try to use it.

I've tried to use the `deviceId` property instead, but I am getting this error:
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Requested device not found` (on a device with a webcam I would get the webcam stream instead of that error). Here is my code:

```
import { desktopCapturer, DesktopCapturerSource } from "electron";

function onLoad(){
    desktopCapturer.getSources({
        thumbnailSize: {
            width: 256,
            height: 256,
        },
        types: ["screen", "window"]
    }, (error: Error, srcs: DesktopCapturerSource[]) => {
        if (error)
            throw error;
        let video: HTMLVideoElement | null = document.querySelector("video");
        for (let src of srcs)
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video:{
                    deviceId : src.id
                }
            }).then((stream:MediaStream)=>{
                if(video){
                    video.srcObject = stream;
                    video.play();
                }
            })
    })
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onLoad);
```

I also tried using `navigator.getDisplayMedia()`, but I wouldn't get the pop-up prompting to select a source as I would get in Chrome. What should I do to get this working? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, at least for new since WebRTC is not yet standardized. Copying the navigator object into a variable and casted to `any` allows the use of the `mandatory` property on the constraints object since typescript no longer checks for type compatibility